# When you set <div> height to 100%, what is technically happening to the other content on the page?

Tags: html, css

Beginner trying to understand the `height` property. Let's say I start with the following basic css and html, setting the hight of the `.hero` div to 100%:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.hero {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
.normal {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="hero">
    <h1>100% Heroic</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="normal">
    <h2>Normal Div</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So there are a couple of things that I don't understand here:

1. What does it mean to set `<html>` height to 100%? As the root element, how is its height calculated? MDN says: "A percentage height on the root element is relative to the initial containing block." However, I have no idea what the "initial containing block" would be for the `<html>` element.
2. So in the snippet above, I have set `<html>`, `<body>` and `.hero` to 100%. As I understand it, height is calculated with reference to the parent (except for the wrinkle specified in item 1 above). So if the `.hero` div is taking up 100% of `<body>`, how is there room left over for the `.normal` div? Does `<body>` automatically expand? If so, does this mean `height: 100%` with respect to `.hero` just means "This class will take up as much of the parent element as possible, but if there's more content in the parent, we'll have to make a little room for it as well." In other words, not quite 100%?

Any help understanding these concepts would be appreciated!!

Comment: There isn't any height left over for the `.normal` div. The content overflows the `<body>`. Try adding `overflow: hidden` to the `body` selector and notice that the `.normal` div isn't shown anymore.

Comment: Does that mean whenever `<body>` height is set to 100%, and we have to scroll down, everything below the fold is overflow? In other words, if we added `overflow: hidden` to the `body` selector for many sites on the internet, most of the content would disappear?

Comment: I think so :). But there is also `min-height: 100%` that should make it at least 100% high. Not sure how that will affect child elements with `height: 100%` though. Sounds like something I should experiment with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using percent to measure something it is nearly always in respect to something else right?

The easiest way to think about `height:100%;` is to start with the window and work your way in.

[image]

Now in the above example, if the height of each of element is set to 100%. Each element will be the full height of the window.

If you you have Element-Overflow <sub>pun intended</sub>, as in elements are being pushed down due to the height of the elements above them. That does not change the height of the body, html or whatever parent element. The best way to see that is with a border and/or `overflow:hidden;`:

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  /*overflow:hidden; add and remove overflow to see what I'm talking about*/
  border:2px solid red;
  }

.hero{
  height:100%;
  }
h1{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hero">
    <h1>100% Heroic</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="normal">
    <h2>Normal Div</h2>
  </div>
```

So the height isn't really going over 100% you just have some overflow. Note that the body, html, and #hero are still only as tall as the window.

Answer (score 0):

The body tag can be set to 100% so any styles applied to that parent tag will be applied at a height of 100% (i.e a background-color/image). If there is other content on the page, the content will take up it's own space and the body element will adjust as needed.Essentially, when an element is set to a height of 100% it will take up 100% of allotted space, in respect to other elements on the page. Hopefully this helps answer your question.

If there is no other content or no parent element, the browser window is used to determine the height/width.

Comment: Becandoo, see ckuijjer's comment above. the `.normal` div is actually overflow.